# cakePHP redirect method double parameter

Tags: cakephp

I am calling a redirect method:

```
$encryptedEmail = "123";
$this->redirect(array("controller" => "claim", "action" => "index", $encryptedEmail));
```

The action I a redirecting to has the following route setup:

```
Router::connect('/claim/index/**', array('controller' => 'claim', 'action' => 'index'));
```

The redirect is sending me to the following url

> /claim/index/123123

For some reason the data I want to pass to the action is being doubled :/

I am doing the redirect as specified the documentation not sure why it's doing that.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `Router::connect('/claim/index/*', ...)`?

Comment: No the double star I need it because it's used to escape / in the parameter value. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes

Comment: Altough that seems to be it ... I have modified the route and the problem is not occouring anymore. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?